# Mismatched ampere

Tags: power-supply

I have a ipcam with a device input rating of 12v 2000mA.

Can I use a 12v 3.33A AC adaptor with it? I haven't tried using it yet, i'm afraid it might cause damage to the device.

Comment: There will be no damage. The camera only draws as much current as it needs, and the supply only provides what is needed no matter if it's rating is higher.

Comment: This question is asked at least once per week. Use tge search function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can use it. Your device will take up to 2A, power supply can give up to 3.33A, so you have 1.33A spare capacity. Just check plug polarity.